# Tensorflow avoid multiple computation of same variable

Tags: caching, tensorflow

I'm pretty new using tensorflow and I'd like to know how can I avoid that a value is computed twice when actually I want to use the same value.

I'm trying to implement k-means by scratch and here's the code that creates the initial points (centroids + samples):

```
def create_samples(n_clusters, n_samples_per_cluster, n_features,
                   min_value=-100, max_value=100, stddev=5.0, seed=None):
    centroids = []
    all_samples = []
    mean = (min_value + max_value) / 2
    for i in range(n_clusters):
        centroid = tf.random_uniform(
            (1, n_features), minval=min_value, maxval=max_value, seed=seed,
            dtype=tf.float64, name='cluster_centroid_{i}'.format(i=i))
        samples = tf.random_normal(
            (n_samples_per_cluster, n_features), mean=mean, stddev=stddev,
            seed=seed, dtype=tf.float64,
            name='cluster_samples_{i}'.format(i=i))

        centroid = tf.Print(centroid, [centroid], message='c = ')
        samples = tf.Print(samples, [samples], message='s1 = ')

        samples += centroid

        samples = tf.Print(samples, [samples], message='s2 = ')

        centroids.append(centroid)
        all_samples.append(samples)

    centroids = tf.concat(0, centroids, name='centroids')
    all_samples = tf.concat(0, all_samples, name='samples')

    return centroids, all_samples
```

I've added the `tf.Print`s for debugging purpose. And here's the code that calls this function:

```
n_clusters = 1
n_samples_per_cluster = 1
n_features = 2
seed = 0
tf.set_random_seed(seed)

centroids, all_samples = create_samples(
    n_clusters, n_samples_per_cluster, n_features, seed=seed)

model = tf.initialize_all_variables()
with tf.Session() as session:
    centroids = session.run(centroids)
    all_samples = session.run(all_samples)
```

Here's the output:

```
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] c = [80.25281165444963 -71.920180669357052]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] c = [-3.3006194509225111 36.307522870893735]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] s1 = [-1.3632952542762977 6.4002734412600155]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] s2 = [-4.6639147051988088 42.707796312153746]
```

Before adding the `tf.Print` and by checking only the output of the function I was really confused on what was happening. As you can see the value of the variable `centroid` is computed twice, I suppose the first time to create the `centroids` variable and the second time when it is summed up to `samples`. As you can imagine it is not what I want, how can I avoid that `centroid` is computed twice for each iteration in the `for` loop? Are there more methods to obtain this behaviour? What is the best practice?

System info:

I'm running Python 3.5.2 with tensorflow 0.11 installed through conda (`conda-forge::tensorflow=0.11.0=py35_0`) on OSX 10.11.

Comment: Technically those are Tensors rather than Variables. Tensors expire at the end of each `session.run` call and have to be recomputed. One solution is to refactor computation to use single `run` calls, like `centroids,all_samples = session.run([centroids, all_samples])

Comment: Adding to @YaroslavBulatov, the reason you are seeing the `centroid` being computed/printed twice is that the `samples` tensor depends on the `centroid` tensor (`samples += centroid`). To evaluate the `samples` tensor in the second `session.run` invocation, tensorflow has to re-evaluate `centroid` in the process of generating `samples`. This is in addition to the first time it was evaluated during the first `session.run` invocation.

Comment: Aside from that, you do not have to invoke `tf.initialize_all_variables()` because your code does not create any variables so far.

Comment: Thanks guys! It's all clear now!